# Jython ImportError: No module named requests in <script> at line number

Tags: java, python, spring, jython

I'm trying to run a python script in my Spring Batch app. An item processor is going to execute the aforementioned script. The problem is that my script needs to import a module and Jython is not finding the module. I tried putting the module directory in the classpath (src/main/resources) but this didn't work.

The script works if I run it with python, so we can discard something there.

Here's the script:

```
import sys
print(sys.path)
import yfinance as yf

print("Processing: {0}".format(item.symbol))
tickerData = yf.Ticker(item.symbol)

dictBalanceSheet = tickerData.get_balance_sheet(as_dict=True)
keyList = dictBalanceSheet.keys()
keyList = list(keyList)
keyList.sort()
earliestDate = keyList[-1]
netIncome = tickerData.financials.at['Net Income', earliestDate]
balanceSheet = tickerData.balance_sheet
numShares = balanceSheet.at['Common Stock', earliestDate]

eps = round(netIncome/numShares, 2) #TODO verificar cuentas si la compañia entrega dividendos
item.eps = eps
```

Maybe the sys.path output will give you more sight, so here's the output of the program:

```
['C:\\Users\\Edgar Hern\xc3\xa1ndez\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\stock-analyzer-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar-spring-boot-libs-8bd68510-6140-4bb8-8ec7-e30f2b9517c4\\Lib', 'C:\\Users\\EDGARH~1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\stock-analyzer-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar-spring-boot-libs-8bd68510-6140-4bb8-8ec7-e30f2b9517c4\\jython-slim-2.7.2.jar\\Lib', '__classpath__', '__pyclasspath__/']
2021-04-13 22:36:23.841 ERROR 6136 --- [           main] o.s.batch.core.step.AbstractStep         : Encountered an error executing step evaluatingStep in job job

org.springframework.scripting.ScriptCompilationException: Could not compile path [C:\Users\Edgar Hern├índez\Documents\Programacion\GIT repos\Stock_Analyzer\stock-analyzer\target\hello-world.py]; nested exception is org.springframework.scripting.support.StandardScriptEvalException: ImportError: No module named requests in <script> at line number 4
        at org.springframework.scripting.support.StandardScriptEvaluator.evaluate(StandardScriptEvaluator.java:157) ~[spring-context-5.3.3.jar!/:5.3.3]
        at org.springframework.batch.item.support.ScriptItemProcessor.process(ScriptItemProcessor.java:64) ~[spring-batch-infrastructure-4.3.1.jar!/:4.3.1]
        at org.springframework.batch.item.support.ScriptItemProcessor$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$b97e2b15.invoke(<generated>) ~[spring-batch-infrastructure-4.3.1.jar!/:4.3.1]
        at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:218) ~[spring-core-5.3.3.jar!/:5.3.3]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:779) ~[spring-aop-5.3.3.jar!/:5.3.3]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163) ~[spring-aop-5.3.3.jar!/:5.3.3]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:750) ~[spring-aop-5.3.3.jar!/:5.3.3]
        at org.springframework.aop.support.DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.doProceed(DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.java:137) ~[spring-aop-5.3.3.jar!/:5.3.3]
        at org.springframework.aop.support.DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.invoke(DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.java:124) ~[spring-aop-5.3.3.jar!/:5.3.3]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.3.jar!/:5.3.3]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:750) ~[spring-aop-5.3.3.jar!/:5.3.3]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:692) ~[spring-aop-5.3.3.jar!/:5.3.3]
        at org.springframework.batch.item.support.ScriptItemProcessor$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$ababb933.process(<generated>) ~[spring-batch-infrastructure-4.3.1.jar!/:4.3.1]
        at org.springframework.batch.item.support.CompositeItemProcessor.processItem(CompositeItemProcessor.java:63) ~[spring-batch-infrastructure-4.3.1.jar!/:4.3.1]
        at org.springframework.batch.item.support.CompositeItemProcessor.process(CompositeItemProcessor.java:52) ~[spring-batch-infrastructure-4.3.1.jar!/:4.3.1]
        at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.SimpleChunkProcessor.doProcess(SimpleChunkProcessor.java:134) ~[spring-batch-core-4.3.1.jar!/:4.3.1]
        at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.SimpleChunkProcessor.transform(SimpleChunkProcessor.java:319) ~[spring-batch-core-4.3.1.jar!/:4.3.1]
        at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.SimpleChunkProcessor.process(SimpleChunkProcessor.java:210) ~[spring-batch-core-4.3.1.jar!/:4.3.1]
        at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.ChunkOrientedTasklet.execute(ChunkOrientedTasklet.java:77) ~[spring-batch-core-4.3.1.jar!/:4.3.1]
        at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep$ChunkTransactionCallback.doInTransaction(TaskletStep.java:407) ~[spring-batch-core-4.3.1.jar!/:4.3.1]
        at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep$ChunkTransactionCallback.doInTransaction(TaskletStep.java:331) ~[spring-batch-core-4.3.1.jar!/:4.3.1]
        at org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionTemplate.execute(TransactionTemplate.java:140) ~[spring-tx-5.3.3.jar!/:5.3.3]
        at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep$2.doInChunkContext(TaskletStep.java:273) ~[spring-batch-core-4.3.1.jar!/:4.3.1]
        at org.springframework.batch.core.scope.context.StepContextRepeatCallback.doInIteration(StepContextRepeatCallback.java:82) ~[spring-batch-core-4.3.1.jar!/:4.3.1]
        at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.getNextResult(RepeatTemplate.java:375) ~[spring-batch-infrastructure-4.3.1.jar!/:4.3.1]
        at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.executeInternal(RepeatTemplate.java:215) ~[spring-batch-infrastructure-4.3.1.jar!/:4.3.1]
        at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.iterate(RepeatTemplate.java:145) ~[spring-batch-infrastructure-4.3.1.jar!/:4.3.1]
        at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep.doExecute(TaskletStep.java:258) ~[spring-batch-core-4.3.1.jar!/:4.3.1]
        at org.springframework.batch.core.step.AbstractStep.execute(AbstractStep.java:208) ~[spring-batch-core-4.3.1.jar!/:4.3.1]
        at org.springframework.batch.core.job.SimpleStepHandler.handleStep(SimpleStepHandler.java:148) ~[spring-batch-core-4.3.1.jar!/:4.3.1]
        at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.JobFlowExecutor.executeStep(JobFlowExecutor.java:68) ~[spring-batch-core-4.3.1.jar!/:4.3.1]
        at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.support.state.StepState.handle(StepState.java:68) ~[spring-batch-core-4.3.1.jar!/:4.3.1]
        at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.support.SimpleFlow.resume(SimpleFlow.java:169) ~[spring-batch-core-4.3.1.jar!/:4.3.1]
        at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.support.SimpleFlow.start(SimpleFlow.java:144) ~[spring-batch-core-4.3.1.jar!/:4.3.1]
        at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.FlowJob.doExecute(FlowJob.java:137) ~[spring-batch-core-4.3.1.jar!/:4.3.1]
        at org.springframework.batch.core.job.AbstractJob.execute(AbstractJob.java:320) ~[spring-batch-core-4.3.1.jar!/:4.3.1]
        at org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher$1.run(SimpleJobLauncher.java:147) ~[spring-batch-core-4.3.1.jar!/:4.3.1]
        at org.springframework.core.task.SyncTaskExecutor.execute(SyncTaskExecutor.java:50) ~[spring-core-5.3.3.jar!/:5.3.3]
        at org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher.run(SimpleJobLauncher.java:140) ~[spring-batch-core-4.3.1.jar!/:4.3.1]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:344) ~[spring-aop-5.3.3.jar!/:5.3.3]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:198) ~[spring-aop-5.3.3.jar!/:5.3.3]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163) ~[spring-aop-5.3.3.jar!/:5.3.3]
        at org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.SimpleBatchConfiguration$PassthruAdvice.invoke(SimpleBatchConfiguration.java:128) ~[spring-batch-core-4.3.1.jar!/:4.3.1]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.3.jar!/:5.3.3]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:215) ~[spring-aop-5.3.3.jar!/:5.3.3]
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy73.run(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.batch.JobLauncherApplicationRunner.execute(JobLauncherApplicationRunner.java:199) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.4.2.jar!/:2.4.2]
        at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.batch.JobLauncherApplicationRunner.executeLocalJobs(JobLauncherApplicationRunner.java:173) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.4.2.jar!/:2.4.2]
        at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.batch.JobLauncherApplicationRunner.launchJobFromProperties(JobLauncherApplicationRunner.java:160) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.4.2.jar!/:2.4.2]
        at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.batch.JobLauncherApplicationRunner.run(JobLauncherApplicationRunner.java:155) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.4.2.jar!/:2.4.2]
        at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.batch.JobLauncherApplicationRunner.run(JobLauncherApplicationRunner.java:150) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.4.2.jar!/:2.4.2]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunner(SpringApplication.java:795) ~[spring-boot-2.4.2.jar!/:2.4.2]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunners(SpringApplication.java:785) ~[spring-boot-2.4.2.jar!/:2.4.2]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:333) ~[spring-boot-2.4.2.jar!/:2.4.2]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1311) ~[spring-boot-2.4.2.jar!/:2.4.2]
        at com.stockanalyzer.stockanalyzer.StockAnalyzerApplication.main(StockAnalyzerApplication.java:156) ~[classes!/:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:49) ~[stock-analyzer-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:107) ~[stock-analyzer-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:58) ~[stock-analyzer-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:88) ~[stock-analyzer-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
Caused by: org.springframework.scripting.support.StandardScriptEvalException: ImportError: No module named requests in <script> at line number 4
```

And here's the Item Processor @Bean . The script is in the target directory:

```
@Bean
    @StepScope
    public ScriptItemProcessor<CompanyScoreKeeper,CompanyScoreKeeper> scriptItemProcessor(@Value("#{jobParameters['script']}") String script) { //TODO cambiar nombre del archivo py
        System.out.println("script path: " + script);
        return new ScriptItemProcessorBuilder<CompanyScoreKeeper,CompanyScoreKeeper>().language("jython").scriptResource(new PathResource(script)).build(); //TODO cambiar ruta del archivo py
    }
```

Comment: Even though this is used in a spring batch app, it is not related to spring batch per se. Hence, I will remove the `spring-batch` tag.

Comment: It seems doubtful that this can work. yfinance has other dependencies that cannot be used in Jython, such as `pandas` and `numpy`. https://github.com/ranaroussi/yfinance/blob/main/requirements.txt

Answer (score 0):

I may be a bit late but but here is a potential solution for this kind of problem.
My project setup and scope:

- Netbeans IDE with Java Maven project which uses Jython 2.7.3 on Windows 11 with embedded JythonInterpreter, see [org.python.util.PythonInterpreter](https://www.javadoc.io/static/org.python/jython-standalone/2.7.1/org/python/util/PythonInterpreter.html) for more information. At some point I make a call from Java to a Python script which contains user-defined modules.

When Jython raised an error "ImportError: No module named X" inside the Netbeans console my python script looked as follows:

```
import sys
import random
from tester_vate import *
from crc16 import *
...
```

So I added sys.path.append('Absolute_path_to_python_scripts'):

```
import sys
sys.path.append('Absolute_path_to_python_scripts')
import random
from tester_vate import *
from crc16 import *
```

This one worked for me. It seems that you have to temporarily add a path to the sys module, so that the interpreter can find your modules.